# Extracting from Json in AWS Athena or Presto

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

My query below does not give me any result

```
 WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT responseelements FROM cloudtrail_logs 
    WHERE useridentity.type = 'Root'
    AND eventname='CreateVpc'
    ORDER BY eventsource, eventname;
        AS blob
    )
    SELECT
      json_extract(blob, '$.vpc.vpcId') AS name,
      json_extract(blob, '$.ownerId') AS projects
    FROM dataset
```

But if I run only the inner query

```
SELECT responseelements FROM cloudtrail_logs 
WHERE useridentity.type = 'Root'
AND eventname='CreateVpc'
ORDER BY eventsource, eventname;
```

it gives me the correct response as a Json

```
{"requestId":"40aaffac-2c53-419e-a678-926decc48557","vpc":{"vpcId":"vpc-01eff2919c7c1da07","state":"pending","ownerId":"347612567792","cidrBlock":"10.0.0.0/26","cidrBlockAssociationSet":{"items":[{"cidrBlock":"10.0.0.0/26","associationId":"vpc-cidr-assoc-04136293a8ac73600","cidrBlockState":{"state":"associated"}}]},"ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet":{},"dhcpOptionsId":"dopt-92df95e9","instanceTenancy":"default","tagSet":{},"isDefault":false}}
```

and if I pass this as data as below

```
WITH dataset AS (

SELECT '{"requestId":"40aaffac-2c53-419e-a678-926decc48557","vpc":{"vpcId":"vpc-01eff2919c7c1da07","state":"pending","ownerId":"347612567792","cidrBlock":"10.0.0.0/26","cidrBlockAssociationSet":{"items":[{"cidrBlock":"10.0.0.0/26","associationId":"vpc-cidr-assoc-04136293a8ac73600","cidrBlockState":{"state":"associated"}}]},"ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet":{},"dhcpOptionsId":"dopt-92df95e9","instanceTenancy":"default","tagSet":{},"isDefault":false}}'

    AS blob
)
SELECT
  json_extract(blob, '$.vpc.vpcId') AS name,
  json_extract(blob, '$.ownerId') AS projects
FROM dataset
```

it gives me result , what I am missing here ? So that I am able to make it run in one shot 
Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the wrong column name in your query, it should be `json_extract(responseelements, '$.vpc.vpcId') AS name` instead of `json_extract(blob, '$.vpc.vpcId') AS name`. The `AS blob` part of this query does nothing since you can't alias an entire query, so take it out.

The `AS blob` works in your last example because you're selecting a value (the json string) into a column and the `AS blob` gives the column a name or *alias* of "blob". In your original query, you're selecting an existing column named `responseelements` so that's what you need to refer to in the `json_extract` function.